# Connecting to Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service using perl Mail::IMAPClient

Tags: perl, email, ssl, exchange-server, imap

I am trying to use Mail::IMAPClient to connect to a MS Exchange mailbox.
Read messages in the INBOX and depending on the contents formats and sends email to other mailboxes.

This snippet program is a test to only connect using IMAP and then disconnect.  The snippet fails to connect, but I can connect using openssl.

```
!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Mail::IMAPClient;

use lib "/usr/local/share/perl5";

my $IMAPserver  = "imapx.servers.net";
my $IMAPuser    = "emailUser";
my $IMAPpass    = "resUliame";
my $IMAPport    = 993;
print "Start\n";
# Attach a client using an SSL socket.
my $client = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
        Server          => $IMAPserver,
        Port            => $IMAPport,
        User            => $IMAPuser,
        Password        => $IMAPpass,
        Ssl             => 1,
        DEBUG           => 1
)
or die "new(): $@";
$client->State(Mail::IMAPClient::Connected);

# Close IMAP connections
$client->logout();
print "Done\n";
```

This is the output I get...

```
Start
Started at Mon Sep 26 10:28:16 2016
Using Mail::IMAPClient version 3.38 on perl 5.010001
Connecting with IO::Socket::SSL PeerAddr imapx.servers.net PeerPort 993 Proto tcp Timeout 600 Debug 1
ERROR: Unable to connect to imapx.servers.net:  at /usr/local/share/perl5/Mail/IMAPClient.pm line 370.
        Mail::IMAPClient::connect(Mail::IMAPClient=HASH(0x2064b98)) called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Mail/IMAPClient.pm line 313
        Mail::IMAPClient::new("Mail::IMAPClient", "Server", "imapx.servers.net", "Port", 993, "User", "emailUser", "Password", "resUliame", ...) called at ./testEmail.pl line 17
new(): Unable to connect to imapx.servers.net:  at ./testEmail.pl line 17
```

I can connect with openssl so I know the server, port, user & passwd is correct.

```
# openssl s_client -connect imapx.servers.net:993 -crlf
CONNECTED(00000003)

* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
* LOGIN emailUser resUliame
* OK LOGIN completed.
* SELECT Inbox
* 28027 EXISTS
* 1 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
* OK [UNSEEN 27544] Is the first unseen message
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 64268] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 46567390] The next unique identifier value
* OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
```

Comment: Are you using openssl in the same context as PHP?  It looks like you're running it as root.  Are there user-specific firewall rules?

Comment: ***`Unable to connect to imapx.servers.net`*** - if I am parsing the exception message correctly, it looks like a DNS problem. In fact ***`ping imapx.servers.net`*** results in ***`ping: cannot resolve imapx.servers.net: Unknown host`***.

Comment: I should have stated that the servername, user and password have been altered to protect the guilty.

Comment: Does your imapx server have a valid SSL cert or is it self signed?  You can test if it is a cert problem by changing the Ssl option to: Ssl => [ 'SSL_verify_mode', 0 ].  If that can connect, then you need to look at your certs.

Comment: Can you not proceed with SSL?